# Find character, text around and extract it in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a problem to find a character, enlarge it by constant number of characters around and return it.

Example of text:

```
Contrary to popular belief, (Lorem Ipsum) is not simply random text. It (has) roots in a piece of ...
```

Expected result:

```
r belief, (Lorem Ipsu
 text. It (has) roots
```

How it should work:

1. find position of "(" - 10 characters
2. find position of "(" + 10 characters
3. extract text with start position of point 1. and end position of point 2. (and store it in a new row)

Please is it possible to do this in Notepad++ or similar software with function Find and Replace? 
I believe this can be done with regex, but I am not able to write it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `(.{10}\(.{10})`
- **Replace With:** `\r\n\1\r\n`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

Depending on your line endings, you may need to change the `\r\n` to `\n` in the replacement.

**Explanation:**

- the regular expressin centers at a literal `(` (it has to be escaped as `\(` due the regex rules)
- it captures the 10 character before and after it with the two `.{10}` sections
- all the 21 character are captured into `\1` (by putting the whole regular expression in unescaped parenthesis)
- the replacement inserts `\1` surrounded by linebreaks (either `\r\n` or `\n`, adopt what you need)

Comment: @JanNovak: If you change both `.{10}` to `.{0,10}` it may find a few occurrences more that will be missed now, such as two open parentheses with less than 10 characters between them.

Comment: Hi Rad. Thank you very much.